# Getting an Adobe Air MD5 of a file to match PHP MD5

Tags: php, javascript, air, md5, filestream

I need two functions, one in PHP and the other in Adobe AIR javascript that can calculate the MD5 hash of a file and return identical results for the same file.

I'm using the MD5 function from PHPJS for javascript:

```
function GetFileMD5(path) {
  var file = new air.File(path);
  if(file.exists) {
    var fileStream = new air.FileStream();              
    fileStream.open(file, air.FileMode.READ);
    var content = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    fileStream.close();
    return md5(content);
  } 
}
```

and in PHP:

```
function GetFileMD5($path) {
  if($file = fopen($path,'rb')) {
    $content = fread($file, $file.size);
    fclose($file);
    return md5($content);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which filestream function to use (instead of readUTFBytes to match fread).  I've tried various combinations.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version is definitely wrong. `$file.size` is generating a nonsensical result, probably something like `"Resource id #7size"`.

A correct (and much simpler) implementation might be:

```
function GetFileMD5($path) {
    return md5(file_get_contents($path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `md5_file` function.